# How to set two views in a controller in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to achieve a thank you page after submitting a form in Zend 1.12

in the index i have form and i want if the validation passes then should go to another view (NOT INDEX) for thank you page. how can i do this in my code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
    $C_form = new Application_Form_Eform();
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
            if ($C_form->isValid($formData)) {
            $this->_helper->redirector('','result');
            exit;
            } else {
            $C_form->populate($formData);
            }
            }
    $this->view->form = C_eform;
}
```

and after that where should i create the .phtml file? in the application\views\scripts\index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [render](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.viewintegration.render):

```
$this->view->render('index/yourotherview.phtml');
```

In this case, `index/` is referring to your `views/scripts/index` folder, and the `yourotherview.phtml` file.

So, all together it would be:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
    $C_form = new Application_Form_Eform();
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        if ($C_form->isValid($formData)) {
            $this->_redirect('/index/result);
        } else {
            $C_form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = C_eform;
}
```

**EDIT:**

From your comment it looks like you just want to be redirected instead of displaying a different view. In this case, it's as easy as creating a new action and making the view for it:

```
public function resultAction() {
    // Code here if you need it
}
```

Then create the file `result.phtml` in the `index/` views directory, and you'll need `$this->_redirect('/index/result');` in the index controller. (See above code)

Comment: not working, when the form is correct, it shows me `An error occurred
Application error` and in the URL doesn't go to index/result or /result ....

Comment: See my edit, I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: cool, worked! Thank you! i might have few other question to open for zend :) i will let you know if so, thank you!