# How can i pass variables in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a form on my index, and when it valid, it redirects to a new view, and i want on that new view to get the name that was entered in the form, how can i do that?

my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
    $eform = new Application_Form_Eform();
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        if ($eform->isValid($formData)) {
            $nameInput  =   $eform->getValue('nameInput');
            $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(array('controller'=> 'index','action' =>'result', 'email' => $nameInput));
            $this->_helper->redirector('result');
            exit;
        } else {
            $eform->populate($formData);
        }
    }

    $this->view->form = $eform;
}

public function resultAction()
{
    $nameInput = $this->_getParam('email');
    $this->view->email = $nameInput;
}
```

result.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->name;?>
```

how can i pass the variable `name` that was entered in the form and display it on the new view of `resultAction` ? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you redirect not process in place?

Comment: Are you using ZF1 or ZF2

Comment: @zerkms well you can see here my question and the answer i applied, if you have a better solution please answer so i would know the best to apply Thanks!

Comment: @Mubo Sorry for not mentioning ZF 1.12

Comment: @Liza: a better solution for *what*? You haven't explained what you're currently doing

Comment: @zerkms what i want to do is to pass the variable `name` from the Index view where the form is displaying and submitting, and after the submitting it goes to result page where i want to echo this variable `name` , how can i do that :) ?

Comment: another question are you using zend_form class  too

Comment: @Mubo yes i'm using Zend_form :)

Comment: @Liza: it's not a task - it's a solution (that presumably doesn't work otherwise you wouldn't be here). Explain the task as it was assigned to you by your manager or whoever assigned it to you. At this moment I don't understand why you need a redirect at all.

Comment: @zerkms there's no task :), i really explained exactly what i want to do, i have a form with a name, lastname, pass ... etc on my index page, and if it's valid, i want to go to a thank you page where i can mention the name of the submitter on the index page, and i just want to pass this `name` and display it in this new view.

Comment: Just pass it via url param or store in session.

Comment: @Liza: so why do you need a redirect?

Comment: @zerkms is there another solution? because i just asked a while ago here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174276/how-to-set-two-views-in-a-controller-in-zend-framework , and didn't know how else to apply one controller with two views :)

Comment: @Liza: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Can you render a view?

Comment: @zerkms sorry but i'm not very good with zend, that's why i asked the question about the redirect and took the advice of the answer there, i don't know what render do :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to execute `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector::direct` method after `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector::gotoRoute`, leave only the first call, and use `gotoRouteAndExit` instead:

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoRouteAndExit (array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     =>'result', 
    'email'      => $nameInput));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i replaced `$this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(array('controller'=> 'index','action' =>'result', 'email' => $nameInput));
     $this->_helper->redirector('result');` with your code, but now it's not even going to the result page ... any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for the update -> now it's going to result page but not displaying the email. the page is empty :( i'm going crazy over this because i don't understand where is the issue :( any ideas?

Comment: i'm using Zend_Form , Zend framework 1.12, and runing on Wamp with rewritemod enabled

Comment: still not showing anything on the result page. and the url is the same as the mentioned earlier

Comment: how can i test that? `$nameInput` should be the email from the `Form` and that is sure not empty because i set it to not be empty in the Form validator

Comment: at least: `var_dump($eform->getValue('nameInput'));die;` . As temporary workaround try: `$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrlAndExit("/index/result/email/{$nameInput}");`

Comment: ok, great, so it's null, but have no idea why, the email is entered by me and then submit.

Comment: what is the name of the email field in your form ?, it should be: `$nameInput = $eform->getValue('NAME_OF_YOUR_INPUT');`

Comment: ok great! it worked, the getValue was getting $nameInput not `email`, but why the URL changed? i want it to stay `/result` not `/result/email/liza@bla.com`

Comment: brr, because you are passing value using `$_GET` request

Comment: and there's no way to pass this `email` value in other methods?

Comment: no there are: DB, Sessions, POST. But that is different question

Comment: Ok i see, thank you very much for sticking around till solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood question. You want send param URI when redirecting. So you can try this.

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
        public function indexAction()
        {
            // action body
            $C_form = new Application_Form_C_form();
                    VALIDATION....


        $nameInput  =   $C_form->getValue('nameInput');

        //Here you redirecting  to result page  
        //and URI PARAM nameInput is sent through HTTP


       $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(array('controller'=> 'index','action' =>'result', 'name' => $nameInput));

        }

        public function resultAction()
        {
        //Here get the PARAM name 
        //from the index Action 
        $nameInput = $this->_getParam('name');
        //If you want to display on the view
        $this->view->name = $nameInput;


        }
}
     // in Result page view 

       //just echo the assigned view like this. 
        <?php echo $this->name;?>
```

Comment: And how is $name displaying in the result page? `<?php echo $this->name;` ?>

Comment: that seems ok. Hope that adds some